# charset Latin1 in Webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a HTML file on myassets folder, i want to display it on a webview. The html is charset=latin1, when I run the app the special characteres like á é í ó ú and others are displayed as strange characters.

This is my webview  code

```
   myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, datos, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

In the HTML file the line look like this :

```
     "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=latin1"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try puttin this within your meta tag

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know if this really matters but try putting the UTF-8 in lower case in the android method.  I just saw it like that and it's working

Comment: explanation needed .. your this answer should be in comment